# Way to insert bit into Binary number in ARM Assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm, mbed

I have a LPC1768 ARM MBED processor. And now i have a binary string in `R1`: `101111`. 
Is there any way that i can make it: `10100111`(i insert 2 "`0`" into the original number) by directly adding bits into the original number?

To be clear, i want to perform this in ARM Assembly language

Comment: Of course there is a way. It's just some bitwise ops. It won't be a single instruction though.

Comment: @Jester I think there actually is a assembly method to do this?

Comment: not an assembly thing just look at the bits and figure out the bitwise (or value to add if you want to do addition instead) operations to do.  work those steps out and then apply them to the target programming language be it arm assembly or something else.

Comment: if its not just this bit pattern but abcdef becomes abc00def then it is bitwise (plus maybe something else, depends on which way is fewer step)

Answer (score 0):

ARM has some decently powerful bitfield instructions which might let you do this efficiently.

- UBFX or just a right-shift to save all the bits above the insert position into another reg.
- Left shift that by the number of zeros to insert
- BFI to insert the high bits (plus added zeros) back into the insert position.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABCIHEF.html

BFI only works with immediate insert position and length, but it replaces the old bits in the destination so you don't have to clear + OR or something.

With runtime-variable position, you'd probably want to AND with `~((1<<n)-1)` to clear all bits above a bit #n, then `or rdst, rsrc, tmp lsl n` to do `x |= tmp<<n`

Answer (score 0):

On Armv7:

```
ubfx    r2, r1, #3, #3
and     r1, r1, #7
bfi     r1, r2, #5, #3
```

On less than v7:

```
lsr     r2, r1, #3
and     r1, r1, #7
orr     r1, r1, r2, lsl #5
```

Comment: @old_timer "reverse engineering" is often the much more efficient way to learn new stuff, especially assembly.